# how to write data in json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Tell me how to implement it. I want to enter a word into the input, it was saved and displayed in the json file. How to do it right?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./style.scss";
import TableWords from "./component/table-words";
import dictionaryFile from "../../dictionary/dictionary.json";

class Dict extends Component {
    render() {
        let dict = dictionaryFile.dictionary;
        return (
            <div className="dict">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="addtext" className="addWords"/>
                    <button className="btn-addWords">Add</button>
                </div>
                {dict.map(elem =>
                    <TableWords engwords={elem.engwords}  ruswords={elem.ruswords} key={elem.index}/>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
"dictionary": [
    {
      "index": "1",
      "engwords": "coat",
      "ruswords": "пальто"
    },
    {
      "index": "2",
      "engwords": "over where",
      "ruswords": "там"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read and write `JSON` files from your `React`/client-side application? If so, you can certainly read a `JSON` file, but you cannot write to a `JSON` file. This is something that you'd need to implement on a backend/server.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a json server with https://github.com/typicode/json-server library. Then use axios for http get and http post for the json server.